# How to pass any type using generics?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Good day

Trying to deal with generics

There are 2 types

1. `TUserInfo`

```
type TUserInfo = {
   id: num,
   readonly fname: string,
   readonly lname: string
}
```

2. `TBody`

```
type TBody = {
   success: boolean,
   user?: any
}
```

Tell me how to pass any type to `TBody` (for example, `TUserInfo`). And `user` should have the same type instead of `any`.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better to use discriminated unions in this case:

```js
export interface User {
    id: number,
    fname: string,
    lname: string
}

type Response<T> =
    | {
        success: true;
        user: T
    }
    | {
        success: false
    }

type Result = Response<User>

declare var result: Result

if (result.success) {
    result.user
} else {
    result.success // false
    result.user // error
}
```

I'd willing to bet that if `success` if `false` - `user` property should be `ubdefined`.

`Result` type is pretty popular monad.
See [Rust Result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/), [F# Result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/results)

Answer (score 1):

In typescript, you can create interfaces.

```
export interface TUserInfo {
    id: number,
    fname: string,
    lname: string
}

export interface TBody {
    success: boolean,
    user?: TUserInfo
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I would like to understand the types

Answer (score 1):

Did so

```
type TBody<T> = {
       success: boolean;
       user?: T;
    }
```